# How to set custom text for django on_delete function?

Tags: python, django, database, django-models

I have a model named 'Clients' and another model named 'Information'.

```
class Information(models.Model):
client_name = models.ForeignKey(Clients, on_delete=models.SET(get_deleted_client_intance))
```

I want to set a custom text when a name is deleted from 'Clients' model.

The below function creates a new name 'deleted' as a new entry and is saved in 'Clients' model. I don't want that. I want if I delete a name it says 'deleted' or 'removed' on it's place.

```
def get_deleted_client_intance():
return Clients.objects.get_or_create(name='deleted')[0]
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a little misunderstanding about `on_delete` keyword argument. According to the docs:

> When an object referenced by a ForeignKey is deleted, Django will emulate the behavior of the SQL constraint specified by the on_delete argument. For example, if you have a nullable ForeignKey and you want it to be set null when the referenced object is deleted:
>
> ```
> user = models.ForeignKey(
>    User,
>    on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
>    blank=True,
>    null=True,
> )
> ```

I.e. it handles some logic when a referenced object is deleted - sets the field as null (SET_NULL), restricts from removing if the referenced object has children (PROTECT), deletes the child objects as well (CASCADE), or sets your preferred value (SET), etc.

In your case, if you want to change the state of the `Clients` object you don't need to do it in the callable passed to `models.SET`, you'd better do it on the object level, e.g. override the `delete` method:

```
class Clients(models.Model):
    ...


    def delete(self, using, *args, **kwargs):
        self.name = 'deleted'
        self.save(using=using)
```